# Emulating `position: fixed;` with javascript, but without it being jumpy, laggy, or having "hickups"

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, css-position

I'm trying to emulate `position: fixed;` using javascript, the reason being that the element has to be inside a scrollable div (overflow-scroll-y), and `position: fixed;` only works relative to the window scroll, not an elements scroll, though normally in a case like this I could fix it by using `position: absolute;` and everything would just work, but the scollable div / container element needs to have `perspective: 1px;` which brakes the `position: absolute;` adjustment, so back to just js emulation.

Now it works, with javascript, but all too often the element in question lags a bit behind the scroll, creating a kind of "jumpy" feeling (it's especially bad on Firefox), that is say it's fixed at the top of the element, if the user scrolls it's suppose to be exactly at the top always, but in reality it sometimes goes a bit (or allot) too high or low, depending on the scrolling direction, and then snaps in place again, this snapping or jumpy effect is undesirable, and is not present in cases where you can fix the element using either `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;`.

I've made a [jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hka3qg0L/14/), if you don't notice the undesirable effect in your browser you can try uncommenting the `increaseLag` function, on my computer the lag is clearly visible on Firefox but not as noticeable on Chrome unless I enable the increaseLag function (I'm running Ubuntu).

How could one tackle this? Is there perhaps a pure css solution I'm missing or an alternative js route?

My current buggy solution uses a scroll event on the container element which updates the `top` css property of the "fixed" element relative to the updated scroll position.

```
$("#container_element").scroll(function() {
    //increaseLag(this);
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $(".fixed_emulation").css("top", scrollTop+"px");
});
```

---

```
#container_element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  perspective: 1px;
}

.fixed_emulation {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

```
<div id="container_element">
  <div class="fixed_emulation"> :) </div>
  <p>Text text text. Text text. Text.</p>
  <p>Text text text. Text text. Text.</p>
  <p>Text text text. Text text. Text.</p>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I have run into same laggy problem. Did you find any solution with JavaScript approach like updating the top value? Is it possible to reduce the laggy behavior while using JavaScript? Any different JavaScript approach that you found? My css solution won't work because of my transform property. Help me out please.